# How to compute the largest value in a column using withColumn?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to compute the largest value of the following DataFrame in Spark **1.6.1**:

```scala
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3)).toDF("id")
```

A first approach would be to select the maximum value, and it works as expected:

```scala
df.select(max($"id")).show
```

The second approach could be to use `withColumn` as follows:

```scala
df.withColumn("max", max($"id")).show
```

But unfortunately it fails with the following error message:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 'id' is neither
>   present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group
>   by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value
>   you get.;

How can I compute the maximum value in a `withColumn` function without any `Window` or `groupBy`? If not possible, how can I do it in this specific case using a `Window`?

Comment: How would you write what you are trying to achieve in plain-old SQL ? If there is a way, it's close to that. (I personnaly do not see intruitively how one cas express a `max` without some kind of aggregation first, either group by - wich is what your second attempt expects, or subquery - which is what your first working sample does), so I *guess* the error is only  natural if you think in terms of SQL.

Answer (score 2):

The right approach is to compute an aggregate as a separate query and combine with the actual result. Unlike window functions, suggested in many answers here, it won't require shuffle to a single partition and will be applicable to large datasets.

It could be done `withColumn` using a separate action:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, max}

df.withColumn("max", lit(df.agg(max($"id")).as[Int].first))
```

but it is much cleaner to use either explicit:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast

df.crossJoin(broadcast(df.agg(max($"id") as "max")))
```

or implicit cross join:

```scala
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", true)

df.join(broadcast(df.agg(max($"id") as "max")))
```

Comment: in your first approach, will `df.agg(max($"id")).as[Int].first` be recomputed for every row in `df` ?

Comment: @vdep `lit` argument is evaluated by value, so no - it is evaluated long before execution of the plan actually happens.

Answer (score -1):

### There are few categories of [functions in Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$).

- Aggregate functions, e.g. max, when we wanna aggregate multiple rows in to one
- None-aggregate functions, abs, isnull, when we wanna transform one column to another
- Collection functions, e.g. explode, when one row will expand to multiple rows.

### Implicit aggregation

They are used to when we wanna aggregate more rows in to one.

The following code internally has an aggregation.

```
df.select(max($"id")).explain

== Physical Plan ==
*HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[max(id#3)])
+- Exchange SinglePartition
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_max(id#3)])
      +- *Project [value#1 AS id#3]
         +- Scan ExistingRDD[value#1]
```

we can also using multiple aggregation functions in a select.

```
df.select(max($"id"), min($"id")).explain
```

### aggregate functions can not mix with none-aggregate functions directly

The following code will report error.

```
df.select(max($"id"), $"id")

df.withColumn("max", max($"id"))
```

Because `max($"id")` has few values then `$"id"`

### aggregate with `over`

In this case the analytic function is applied and presented for all rows in the result set.

We can use

```
df.select(max($"id").over, $"id").show
```

Or

```
df.withColumn("max", max($"id").over).show
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me : `not enough arguments for method over`, I should have mentioned I'm using Spark 1.6.0. Is it a new feature in Spark 2.x ?

Comment: Yes. Before Spark 2.0.0, `over`must using with a `window` parameter.

Comment: Since I'm using Spark 1.6 I'm going to stick with my answer, but thank you for your thorough answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is Spark **2.0** here.

With `withColumn` and window functions it could be as follows:

```
df.withColumn("max", max('id) over)
```

Note the empty `over` which is to assume a "empty" window (and is equivalent of `over ()`).

If you however need a more complete `WindowSpec` you can do the following (again, this is 2.0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
// the trick that has performance cost (!)
val window = Window.orderBy()
df.withColumn("max", max('id) over window).show
```

Please note that the code has a serious performance issue as reported by Spark itself:

> WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.